# Send dalayed EIP1559 transaction

Tags: transactions, fees, eip-1559

I'm trying to generate new EIP1559 transaction at 11:00. My goal is that after the transaction was sent I'll get 0 balance on the wallet. But the issue is that after I sign this transaction I'll broadcast it to blockchain at 11:30 for example. And for these 30 minutes `baseFee` may increase and I'll get an error insufficient balance. Is it possible to somehow handle such a case with new tx protocol?